# How to use Python/R to analyze a joined table in Power BI?

Tags: python, merge, powerbi, transform

I just try to use R/Python in Power BI. Now I know how to analyze data when reading data from `Get Data`. But when I use `Edit Queries > Merge Queries` to merge two or more tables together, I cannot use the same way to analyze the data.

Let's say I have two tables. One is hometown:

```
id  name    score   hometown
1   zhao    65  china
2   qian    98  china
3   sun 100 australia
4   li  45  xinxiang
5   zhou    98  zhengzhou
```

The other one is school:

```
id  school  math    chinese english
1   s1  12  87  87
2   s1  546 546 54
3   s2  21  12  15
4   s3  54  84  798
5   s34 98  65  35
6   s1  65  8   156
7   s2  45  98  15
8   s4  12  549 89
9   s4  56  15  87
10  s4  8974    2   98
```

Then I merge these two tables together using the field 'id', generating a new table called 'my':

[image]

Then I want to run some Python/R on this data, so in 'Transform-->Run Python script', I put my code like:

```
import pandas as pd
myid=dataset
myid.loc[:,'population']=myid.loc[:,'population']*100
dataset=myid
```

But I have got the following error:

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'my' (step 'Run Python script') references
>   other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source.
>   Please rebuild this data combination.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not directly answer the question but this post; 
https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/11/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/ 
suggests that you need to have queries like your merge loaded into a staging query first.

This post from the Power BI forum will certain explain it much better than I am:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Formula-Firewall-Query-references-other-queries-so-it-may-not/td-p/18619/page/2.

Hope this helps!